# Help me remember which is which: "humoro" and "humuro"

Tags: learning

I keep mixing these up. In Swedish, one is *humor* and the other *humör*. Moreover, the English word *humour* is similar to both. Can anyone think of a memory rule or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the French language you have the same difficulty (*humeur* - *humour*).

[image]
([image source](http://www.edukado.net/biblioteko/fotoj?f=519))

I remembered the word *humuro* by the sentence: *Ridi kiam oni kuras kontraŭ la **muro** estas malbona hu-**muro***.

The other way is to look on the English word *m-**oo**-d* (which means *hum-**o**-ro*).

Answer (score 10):

I remember it this way.

- The U in *humUro* is smiling (at something funny).
- The other one (*humoro*) means mood.